# Wrong Positioning of Font Awesome Icon in Input Box in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, font-awesome

I have created a custom search box with a font awesome info icon on the right side inside the search box. Hovering over this icon gives the user more information about the required input format. It does work nicely for Firefox and Safari (IE not tested), but in Google Chrome, the info icon gets positioned below the input box. Vertical position, however, is correct.

```css
.SearchBox input {
  flex: 1!important;
  height: 35px!important;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0!important;
  z-index: 100!important;
  background: #fcfcfc!important;
  border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4!important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece!important;
  border-left: 1px solid #cecece!important;
  border-right: 1px solid #cecece!important;
  margin-left: 0px!important;
  font: inherit!important;
  outline: none!important;
  /* remove focus ring from Webkit */
  line-height: 1.2!important;
  padding: 5px!important;
  padding-left: 12px!important;
  padding-right: 36px!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  /* <-- Set size to 100% */
  font-size: 15px!important;
  transition: 0.15s ease-in!important;
}

.right-inner-addon {
  position: relative!important;
}

.right-inner-addon input {
  padding-right: 30px!important;
}

.right-inner-addon i {
  position: absolute!important;
  right: 1px!important;
  padding: 10px 8px!important;
  cursor: pointer!important;
}

.fa-searchinfo {
  color: #808287!important;
  font-size: 11.5pt!important;
}

.fa-searchinfo:hover {
  color: #565859!important;
  font-size: 11.5pt!important;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<div class="SearchBox">
  <div class="right-inner-addon">
    <input name="searchquery" type="text" id="sfq" size="35" maxlength="15000" class="tftextinput2" placeholder="enter ID" value="" />
    <a title="Some detailed information about possible input formats." class="fa-searchinfo"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" ></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Firefox 65.0 does not work for me either.

Comment: That's true. When running the code snipped in Firefox 65.0, I just realized that it does wrongly position the icon as well. On my virtual host it does work, the only difference is that I load an older version of fontawesome from local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace .right-inner-addon i with below css :

```
.right-inner-addon a {
    position: absolute!important;
    right: 1px!important;
    top:6px!important;
    padding: 10px 8px!important;
    cursor: pointer!important;
}
```

```css
.SearchBox input {
  flex: 1!important;
  height: 35px!important;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0!important;
  z-index: 100!important;
  background: #fcfcfc!important;
  border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4!important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece!important;
  border-left: 1px solid #cecece!important;
  border-right: 1px solid #cecece!important;
  margin-left: 0px!important;
  font: inherit!important;
  outline: none!important;
  line-height: 1.2!important;
  padding: 5px!important;
  padding-left: 12px!important;
  padding-right: 36px!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  font-size: 15px!important;
  transition: 0.15s ease-in!important;
  -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-in!important;
  -moz-transition: 0.15s ease-in!important;
  -ms-transition: 0.15s ease-in!important;
}
.right-inner-addon {
  position: relative!important;
}
.right-inner-addon input {
  padding-right: 30px!important;
}
.right-inner-addon a {
  position: absolute!important;
  right: 1px!important;
  top:6px!important;
  padding: 10px 8px!important;
  cursor: pointer!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="SearchBox"> 
  <div class="right-inner-addon">
    <input name="searchquery" type="text" id="sfq" size="35" maxlength="15000" class="tftextinput2" placeholder= "enter ID" value= "" />
    <a title="Some detailed information about possible input formats." class = "fa-searchinfo" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" ></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.SearchBox input {
    flex: 1!important;
    height: 35px!important;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0!important;
    z-index: 100!important;
    background: #fcfcfc!important;
    border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4!important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece!important;
    border-left: 1px solid #cecece!important;
    border-right: 1px solid #cecece!important;
    margin-left: 0px!important;
    font: inherit!important;
    outline:none!important; /* remove focus ring from Webkit */
    line-height: 1.2!important;
    padding: 5px!important;
    padding-left: 12px!important;
    padding-right: 36px!important;
    width: 100%!important;  /* <-- Set size to 100% */
    font-size: 15px!important;
    transition: 0.15s ease-in!important;

    }

.right-inner-addon {
    position: relative!important;
}

.right-inner-addon input {
    padding-right: 30px!important;    
}


.span {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 6px;
       margin-top:-30px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="SearchBox"> 
<div class="right-inner-addon">
<input name="searchquery" type="text" id="sfq" size="35" maxlength="15000" class="tftextinput2" placeholder= "enter ID">
<a title="Some detailed information about possible input formats." class = "fa-searchinfo" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle span"></i></a>

</div>
</div>
```